# How to implementing timer interrupt with a sensor device using A0 and A1 pins

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, timers, adc, analog-sampling

I was wondering if there is a way to program a timer interrupt to collect sensor data at a specific sampling rate?

I want to attach two strain gauge sensors to A0 and A1 pins and collect the data at a 20Hz sampling frequency using a timer interupt on an Arduino Uno. Please, let me know if this is possible, or if there is something else I can do.

Comment: you could just watch millis(), and read A0 and A1 when 20 ms elapses  ... if you still want to use an interrupt, then set a flag in the ISR ... check the flag in loop() and take readings when flag is set ... both ways are very similar

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example and convert it to 'ReadWithoutDelay'

Comment: If you need cycle-accurate timings, you can configure the ADC to be triggered by a timer event (not an interrupt, just the event). Then you would use the ADC interrupt to retrieve the result. This requires studying the datasheet and diving into the intricate details of the hardware. If you do not care about sub-millisecond inaccuracies, timing with `micros()` à la “Blink without delay” will be good enough and way easier.

Comment: Do the two reading need to be at (almost) the same time, or is it also acceptable to sample a 40Hz, and alternate between A0 and A1?

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the respond,